How to link 3 tables where 2 of them are many-to-many?
We have a problem in our schema design for our database that I would like to figure out the cleanest way to solve. The three models are defined in these simplified Django model classes:
class Animal(Model):
    name = CharField()
    infusion_rate = FloatField()
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)  # but with specific tracer concentrations?

class Infusate(Model):
    name = CharField()
    tracers = ManyToManyForeignKey(Tracer)

class Tracer(Model):
    name = CharField()

Currently, we have a through model for the Infusate:Tracer M:M relationship that adds a concentration float field:
class InfusateTracer(Model):
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)
    tracer = ForeignKey(Tracer)
    concentration = FloatField()

but we need to link the Animal model to a single infusate, but with specific concentrations for each of its multiple tracers. In other words, how do I relate an animal to a single infusate, but multiple tracers with specific concentrations belonging to that one infusate?
I was thinking that I could add a field to InfusateTracer and have Animal link to that instead. Let's call it animal, so:
class InfusateTracer(Model):
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)
    tracer = ForeignKey(Tracer)
    concentration = FloatField()
    animal = IntegerField()

but how do I enforce that the relationship between infusate and animal fields in the InfusateTracer model is M:1 (i.e. InfusateTracer.animal never co-occurs with multiple different InfusateTracer.infusate values (but multiple InfusateTracer.tracer values))? Is there some sort of unique constraint I can use to enforce that?
From a different angle, I could create an AnimalTracer linking/through model, but then I would have the same difficulty of retrieving a single unique infusate name associated with the animal.
Trying to figure out the most elegant solution that maintains data integrity is melting my brain.

I was thinking about this again this morning and I had an alternate idea.
To think of the problem another way, I want to be able to link an animal to an infusate (which defines a set of tracers without concentrations). That is one link. When I have an animal, I want to essentially add an annotation to the InfusateTracer table (but I cannot put it directly in that table). It is as if I want to add a concentration field to the InfusateTracer table, so to do it without changing that table, I just have to link to it... So that's what I should do instead of independently linking the animal table to the tracer table to define the concentrations, I should link the animal table to the InfusateTracer table using a linking table (because it is a many to many relationship). In other words, I am annotating the links between infusate and tracer. The relationships would look like this:
class Animal(Model):
    name = CharField()
    infusion_rate = FloatField()
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)

class Infusate(Model):
    name = CharField()
    tracers = ManyToManyForeignKey(Tracer)

class Tracer(Model):
    name = CharField()

class InfusateTracer(Model):
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)
    tracer = ForeignKey(Tracer)

class AnimalInfusateTracer(Model):
    animal = ForeignKey(Animal)
    infusate_tracer = ForeignKey(InfusateTracer)
    concentration = FloatField()

I think this is the answer because I don't have to worry about synchronizing two sets of multiple independent links from infusate to tracer and from animal to tracer (so that they each link to the same set).
When I am loading data, all I have to worry about is looking for infusatetracer records That have the correct infusate and correct tracer!

Seeing the misunderstanding in @Dante's answer (due to me not clearly describing the problem), and trying to figure out how to explain it, I think I figured out a way to solve it!
The problem is that that both Animal and Infusate have a many-to-many relationship with Tracer.  Right now, the concentrations are in the through table between Infusate and Tracer, which is the problem.  It's only when there's an Animal when you have a concentration.  The Infusate should only ever describe a group of Tracers - not at specific concentrations.
I think the solution is that Animal should not link to Infusate at all.  It should have its own M:M relationship with Tracer like this:
class AnimalTracer(Model):
    animal = ForeignKey(Animal)
    tracer = ForeignKey(Tracer)
    concentration = FloatField()

And just remove the concentration from InfusateTracer:
class InfusateTracer(Model):
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)
    tracer = ForeignKey(Tracer)

Then, Animal shouldn't link to Infusate at all:
class Animal(Model):
    name = CharField()
    infusion_rate = FloatField()

The only problem with this is how to get from Animal to Infusate.name (because on our website, we want to say what group of tracers were infused into the animal).  For example, a common infusate is the 6 essential amino acids.  That infusate record has a name: "6eaas".  So if the only link between Animal and infusate is:
Animal -> AnimalTracer -> Tracer -> InfusateTracer -> Infusate
...how to we retrieve the Infusate.name for the Animal page?
I could do it in code...  I could write a method that gathers the tracers from AnimalTracer and then looks for an infusate that has the same tracers... but that's pretty inefficient.
We could keep the link in Animal, like this:
class Animal(Model):
    name = CharField()
    infusion_rate = FloatField()
    infusate = ForeignKey(Infusate)

But then there's the potential that that infusate links to different tracers than AnimalTracer has to specify the concentrations...
It would be nice if there was a way to make all the relationships work together and be enforced by uniqueconstraints...

Check EDIT TWO in my anser.I think most scenerios are covered with no duplicates plus I have added the db constraints to avoid dups

You should not put animal field in InfusateTracer as we can already get the information from the infusate animal field.Instead your model should be like below if you want one animal to have only one record of infusate.
from django.db import models

class Tracer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                models.functions.Lower("name"),
                name="unique_lowercased tracer name",
            ),
        ]


class Infusate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tracers = models.ManyToManyField(Tracer, through='InfusateTracer')

class AnimalName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                models.functions.Lower("name"),
                name="unique_lowercased tracer name",
            ),
        ]

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(AnimalName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    infusion_rate = models.FloatField()
    infusate = models.ForeignKey(Infusate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'infusate'], name='unique_animal_name_infusate')# If an animal is limited to one infusate else use the one below to avoid dups
 models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'infusate','infusion_rate'], name='unique_animal_name_infusate_and_rate')

        ]

class InfusateTracer(models.Model):
    infusate = models.ForeignKey(Infusate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tracer = models.ForeignKey(Tracer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    concentration = models.FloatField()


For more info on enforcing unique constraints check the docs
EDIT
from yourapp.models import Tracer, Infusate, Animal, InfusateTracer

# Step 1: Create Tracer instances
tracer1,_ = Tracer.objects.get_or_create(name='Tracer1')
tracer2,_ = Tracer.objects.get_or_create(name='Tracer2')

# Step 2: Create Infusate instance
infusate = Infusate.objects.create(name='Infusate1')

# Add InfusateTracer instances for the infusate
InfusateTracer.objects.create(infusate=infusate, tracer=tracer1, concentration=0.5)
InfusateTracer.objects.create(infusate=infusate, tracer=tracer2, concentration=1.0)

# Step 3: Create Animal instance and link it to the Infusate
animal_name,_=AnimalName.objects.get_or_create(name='Animal1')
animal = Animal.objects.create(name=animal_name, infusion_rate=10.0, infusate=infusate)

print("Animal created:", animal)
# To get tracers for a certain infusate
infusate_tracers = infusate.tracers
# To get tracers for a certain infusate and animal
infusate_tracers = animal.infusate.tracers

Suppose we want to add another animal using same tracers and concetration you could create another Infusate with same name since ids are going to be different it should be fine.
infusate2 = Infusate.objects.create(name='Infusate1')
InfusateTracer.objects.create(infusate=infusate2, tracer=tracer1, concentration=1.5)
InfusateTracer.objects.create(infusate=infusate2, tracer=tracer2, concentration=2.0)
animal_name2,_=AnimalName.objects.get_or_create(name='Animal2')
animal2 = Animal.objects.create(name=animal_name2, infusion_rate=15.0, infusate=infusate2)

EDIT TWO
Considering the requirements mentioned in the comments below is a new db structure proposed.
# type: ignore

from django.db import models


class Tracer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            models.functions.Lower("name"),
            name="unique_lowercased_tracer_name",
        ),
    ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class Infusate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            models.functions.Lower("name"),
            name="unique_lowercased_infusate_name",
        ),
    ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            models.functions.Lower("name"),
            name="unique_lowercased_animal_name",
        ),
    ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class TracerConcentration(models.Model):
    tracer = models.ForeignKey(Tracer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    concentration = models.FloatField()
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["tracer", "concentration"],
            name="unique_tracer_concentration",
        ),
    ]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.concentration}"


class AnimalInfusate(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    infusion_rate = models.FloatField()
    infusate = models.ForeignKey(Infusate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tracers = models.ManyToManyField(TracerConcentration)
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["tracer", "concentration"],
            name="unique_animal_infusate",
        ),
    ]
    # THe constraint above will ensure a certain animal say a Dog,has only one tracer-concentration
    # values for a specific infusate..That means the infusate-animal pair is gonna happen once.
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # In case an animal can have the same infusate but at different infusate rate then use the three fields
    # in unique contraint. This will also allow different tracer-concentration for that second infusion_rate.
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.infusion_rate}"

With the new structure you get:-

Unique Animal Record.
Unique Tracer Record
Unique Infusate Record
For a particular Animal-Infusate relation,you are going to get a unique tracer-concentrations for mixing with the Infusate.

# Assuming you already have the records
dog=Animal.objects.get(name='Dog')
infusate=Infusate.objects.get(name='infusate')
dog_infusate=AnimalInfusate.objects.get(animal=dog,infusate=infusate)
tracers=dog_infusate.tracers#Get all tracers that can be used.This will always be unique for animal-infusate combination


You can always store infusate information for different animals with no problem

# Create tracers
tracer1 = Tracer.objects.create(name="Tracer A")
tracer2 = Tracer.objects.create(name="Tracer B")
tracer3 = Tracer.objects.create(name="Tracer C")
# Create Infusates
infusate1 = Infusate.objects.create(name="Infusate 1")
infusate2 = Infusate.objects.create(name="Infusate 2")
#Create animals
animal1 = Animal.objects.create(name="Animal 1")
animal2 = Animal.objects.create(name="Animal 2")
# Create concentrations
concentration1 = TracerConcentration.objects.create(tracer=tracer1, concentration=0.5)
concentration2 = TracerConcentration.objects.create(tracer=tracer2, concentration=1.2)
concentration3 = TracerConcentration.objects.create(tracer=tracer3, concentration=0.8)
# Finally
animal_infusate1 = AnimalInfusate.objects.create(animal=animal1, infusion_rate=2.0, infusate=infusate1)
animal_infusate1.tracers.set([concentration1, concentration2])

animal_infusate2 = AnimalInfusate.objects.create(animal=animal2, infusion_rate=3.5, infusate=infusate2)
animal_infusate2.tracers.set([concentration2, concentration3])
# Use same concentration from animal1 with animal2
animal_infusate3 = AnimalInfusate.objects.create(animal=animal2, infusion_rate=2.0, infusate=infusate1)
# The concentrations are set separately so they can be changed
animal_infusate1.tracers.set([concentration1, concentration2])



I don't get it. How does this allow me to specify individual tracer concentrations for a particular animal? Perhaps I didn't explain this well enough in the question. There can be multiple links between an infusate and a particular tracer at different concentrations. For example, you can have two animals linking to the same infusate, but with different concentrations for each tracer. I don't think your suggestion handles this.

I should also point out that for any particular infusate, it should always link to the same group of tracers. It is when there is an animal that has that infusate, when there should be different sets of concentrations for those tracers in that infusate.

Infusate and Tracer are separate tables.InfusateTracer is a many to many table used on Infusate to add more info on Tracers.I think I still dont get what you want to implement maybe you can provide a table

To get concentration for a specific animal you have to choose the Tracer and Infusate and add the concentration there.SO thats one.Now to link the concentration which is stored in  InfusateTracer.You have to link the infusate to the Animal model

I just added an answer that perhaps explains the problem better.  It's not that I want to retrieve 1 set of concentrations in the link from Animal to Infusate.  Each Animal has its own unique set of tracer concentrations to potentially the same infusate.  My answer may elucidate this better.  It's not perfect, and doesn't have a way to enforce the data integrity.

So given your example you added, how would one link a second animal to the same infusate, but with different tracer concentrations.  Then, once you have that, how do you get the right set of concentrations for each animal.  They key here is that an infusate should only be a unique group of tracers (regardless of concentrations) and a tracer should be unique as well.

Oooh now I see where the problem is.Can I ask if an Infusate can be reused to a different animal with the same tracer and same concentration?

It's possible, yes.  There are some infusates with the same tracers at the same concentrations that are re-used under different experimental conditions (like changing the diet) - but with different animals.

I have updated my answer and I think for that scenerio you should use get_or_create to avoid dups..In combination to that you can use a unique constraint in the through table to ensure no duplication occur

The whole point is to have unique records all around.  An infusate name should only occur once & there should only exist one infusate record for any grouping of tracers. A tracer should only occur once. An animal should only occur once. This is why it's hard. Our temporary solution is that the infusate name includes the concentrations in it, but that duplicates the groupings of tracers, which we don't want. I actually still think that the only way we're going to be able to achieve this is either via code or somehow putting an animal value in InfusateTracer with some sort of unique constraint
